# Do we have any api in guava in which i can create hashmap with hashmap as value

Tags: java, collections, guava

I want to create a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Long>>`
I know in guava we have HashMultimap which is `HashMap<String, HashSet<String>`
but do we have some support for `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Long>>` as well??

yes i can do that in core java, just looking for some library where i won't have to check that a key exists everytime

I am explaining my problem with an example::
We have a device manufacturer, device name and device rank

now i need to return 
list of devices for requested manufacturer - fewer requests
rank for particular device and manufacturer - lots of requests

In my case list of manufacturer and list of devices per manufacturer are quite big

any suggestion for an alternate datastructure is also welcomed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you might want a [`Table`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) - possibly a [`HashBasedTable<String, String, Long>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html).